# Weird behaviour of NDSolve when refining the mesh

Tags: finite-element-method

I'm solving Laplace equation on custom defined region:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
R = 1; h = 1;
a = 0.1; b = 0.1;
far = 5;
Ω = ImplicitRegion[((x^2 + y^2 >= R^2) || (z > h/2) || (z < -(h/2))),
{{x, -far R, far R}, {y, -far R, far R}, {z, -far R, far R}}];
    mesh = ToElementMesh[Ω, MaxCellMeasure -> a, MaxBoundaryCellMeasure -> b];
```

The region is just a cube (-5,5), (-5,5), (-5,5) with a cylinder-shaped hole with radius 1 and height 1 placed in the center.

This is the equation I'm solving

```
BCFar = DirichletCondition[V[x, y, z] == -z, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 >= 4 R^2];
Vfun = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[V[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 
    NeumannValue[0, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 4 R^2], BCFar}, V, {x, y, z} ∈ mesh]
```

And finally, extracting $H = - \vec{\nabla} V$

```
Hx[x_, y_, z_] = -Derivative[1, 0, 0][Vfun][x, y, z];
Hy[x_, y_, z_] = -Derivative[0, 1, 0][Vfun][x, y, z];
Hz[x_, y_, z_] = -Derivative[0, 0, 1][Vfun][x, y, z];
```

**I would like to refine the mesh.** However, if I make `a` and `b` smaller, the solution is actually messier (see down for results) and for a = b = 0.08, the solution is just $V = -z$, as if the Neumann BC was not there. Isn't this a little contraintuitive? Can someone explain this weird behaviour please?

Here comes the visualisation of the solution for $H$ generated by

```
DensityPlot[
 Norm@{Hx[x, 0, z], Hy[x, 0, z], Hz[x, 0, z]}, {x, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5},
  PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{0, RGBColor[0.29, 0.66, 1.]}, {1, 
       White}, {1.5, RGBColor[1., 0.53, 0.08]}}, #] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 Epilog -> Rectangle[{-R, -(h/2)}, {R, h/2}]]
```

for a = b = 0.1
[image]

Now for 0.09:
[image]

And finally for 0.08 (literally nothing)
[image]

Comment: How do you generate the plots?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, edited to add the code for the density plot I'm using.

Comment: What version do you use?

Comment: I use 11.1 version of Mathematica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What follows I have tried in version 11.3. I no longer have 11.1 installed so I can not tell much is working in 11.1.

First of all your results do not look as bad in version 11.3. The main problem is that the boundary mesh generator does not do too well for this implicit region:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
R = 1; h = 1;
a = b = 0.08;
far = 5;
\[CapitalOmega] = 
  ImplicitRegion[((x^2 + y^2 >= R^2) || (z > 
       h/2) || (z < -(h/2))), {{x, -far R, far R}, {y, -far R, 
     far R}, {z, -far R, far R}}];
mesh = ToElementMesh[\[CapitalOmega], MaxCellMeasure -> a, 
  MaxBoundaryCellMeasure -> b]
```

If you inspect the mesh at the inner cylinder:

```
eps = 1;
mesh["Wireframe"[
  PlotRange -> {{R^2 - eps, R^2 + eps}, {R^2 - eps, R^2 + eps}, {-h/2,
      h/2}}]]
```

[image]

The edges are not really straight. To do better we proceed as follows. Specify the region differently:

```
r1 = RegionDifference[Cuboid[far {- R, -R, -R}, far {R, R, R}], 
  Cylinder[{{0, 0, -h/2}, {0, 0, h/2}}, R^2]]
```

Use BoundaryDiscretizeRegion before taking the region difference:

```
r2 = BooleanRegion[r1[[1]], BoundaryDiscretizeRegion /@ r1[[2]]];

mesh = ToElementMesh[r2, MaxCellMeasure -> a, 
  MaxBoundaryCellMeasure -> b]


eps = 1;
mesh["Wireframe"[
  PlotRange -> {{R^2 - eps, R^2 + eps}, {R^2 - eps, R^2 + eps}, {-h/2,
      h/2}}]]
```

[image]

Computing the solution:

```
BCFar = DirichletCondition[V[x, y, z] == -z, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 >= 4 R^2];
Vfun = NDSolveValue[{Laplacian[V[x, y, z], {x, y, z}] == 0, BCFar}, 
   V, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh];
Hx[x_, y_, z_] = -Derivative[1, 0, 0][Vfun][x, y, z];
Hy[x_, y_, z_] = -Derivative[0, 1, 0][Vfun][x, y, z];
Hz[x_, y_, z_] = -Derivative[0, 0, 1][Vfun][x, y, z];
DensityPlot[
 Norm@{Hx[x, 0, z], Hy[x, 0, z], Hz[x, 0, z]}, {x, -5, 5}, {z, -5, 5},
  PlotRange -> {-2, 2}, 
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{{0, RGBColor[0.29, 0.66, 1.]}, {1, 
       White}, {1.5, RGBColor[1., 0.53, 0.08]}}, #] &), 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, PlotPoints -> 200, 
 Epilog -> Rectangle[{-R, -(h/2)}, {R, h/2}]]
```

[image]

Which looks good to me. But we can do better: We create a NumericalRegion and attach a boundary mesh to that. When we then generate the full mesh and ask for boundary improvements we gain a bit more accuracy.

```
nr = ToNumericalRegion[r1];
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[r2, "RegionHoles" -> {{0, 0, 0}}];
SetNumericalRegionElementMesh[nr, bmesh]
mesh = ToElementMesh[nr, "ImproveBoundaryPosition" -> True]
```

Note that we do not further refine the boundary or the mesh (less elements)

If we compare how well the meshes approximate the region we get:

```
exact = Integrate[1, {x, y, z} \[Element] r1]
1000 - Pi

exact - NIntegrate[1, {x, y, z} \[Element] mesh]
-0.00029366079219173`

exact - NIntegrate[
  1, {x, y, z} \[Element] 
   ToElementMesh[r2, MaxCellMeasure -> a, MaxBoundaryCellMeasure -> b]]
-0.005857252225961673`
```

With this you should be able to squeeze out some more accuracy.

Comment: I have no idea what BooleanRegion[r1[[1]], BoundaryDiscretizeRegion /@ r1[[2]]] does, but when I try to evaluate it MMA complains: BoundaryDiscretizeRegion::regp: A correctly specified region expected at position 1 of BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[{{0,0,-(1/2)},{0,0,1/2}}].

Comment: @user16320, yea, you'd probably need a newer version for that to work. Do you have a means of getting that upgrade?

Comment: Is 11.3 necessarily needed for this to run?

Comment: It works for me now. How can I refine the elements near the cylinder even further? MaxBoundaryCellMeasure refines also the box elements which isn't good (there's too much of them and refining outer boundary is wasteful in this situation).

Comment: @user16320, what works not for you? You can refine one of the calls to BoundaryDiscretizeRegion and the other not.

Comment: I had to specify r2 = BooleanRegion[
   r1[[1]], {BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[r1[[2, 1]]], 
    BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[r1[[2, 2]], MaxCellMeasure -> a]}]; instead of r2 = BooleanRegion[r1[[1]], BoundaryDiscretizeRegion /@ r1[[2]]]; and now it works, thanks!

Comment: @user16320, great.

Comment: However, the solution is still not precise enough - no matter how I refine the inner boundary, the H-field still looks like crumpled paper. Is this problem of the method NDSolve uses (not sure what the internal routines are, I once implemented some primitive Laplace equation solver in C++ and the solution can be made sufficiently smooth), or the derivative of interpolation function in more than 1D? Should I open another question about derivative of interpolations spitted out of NDSolve? I'm desperate here :(

Comment: @user16320, it's probably best to ask a new question; I need to attend other things right now.